# memory range sharing in threads : ensure data is not stuck in cache

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

When sending address of memory location from one thread to another, how to ensure that data is not stuck in CPU cache, and that the second thread actually reads the correct value ? ( I'm using a socketpair() to send the 
pointer from one thread to another )

And related question , how does c++ compiler, along with thread primitives, figure out what memory address need to be handled specially for synchronozations.

```
struct Test { int  fld; }

thread_1 ( ) {
  Test *ptr1 = new Test;
  ptr1->fld = 100;
  ::write(write_fd, &ptr1, sizeof(ptr1));
}

thread_2 () {
  Test *ptr2;
  ::read(read_fd, &ptr2, sizeof(ptr2));
  // WHAT MAGIC IS REQUIRED TO ENSURE THIS ?
  assert(ptr2->fld == 100 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the value between threads in the same process, I would ensure that `std::atomic<int>` as the type of field, and the related setter and getter functions. Obviously, passing a pointer from one process to another doesn't work at all, unless it's from an area of memory that is guaranteed to have the same address in both processes - shared memory for example, but then you shouldn't need sockets...

Compilers do not, in general, know how to deal with caches, except for `atomic` types (technically, atomics are usually dealt with using separate instructions, rather than cache-flushing and cache-invalidation, and the processor hardware handles the relevant "talk to other processors about the cache content").

The OS (subject to bugs of course) does that sort of thing when passing between processes - or within processes. But for passing pointers, you can't rely on that, the newly received pointer value is correct, but the content the pointer is pointing at isn't cache-managed.

In some processors, you can use a memory barrier to the correct order of memory content between threads. This forces the processor to "perform all memory operations before this point". However, in the case of system calls like `read` and `write`, the OS should take care of that for you, and ensure that the memory has been properly written to before the `read` starts to read the memory it wants to store in the socket buffer, and `write` will have a memory barrier after it's stored your data (in this case the value of the pointer, but memory barriers affect all reads and/or writes that preceed that point).

If you were to implement your own primitives for passing data, and the processors do not have cache coherency (most of the modern processors do), you will also need to add a cache-flush for the writing side, and a cache invalidate for the reading side. This is architecture dependent, there is no support for this in standard C or C++ (and in some processors, only OS functionality [kernel mode] can flush or invalidate cache content, in other processors it can be done in user-mode code - the granularity of such operations also varies, it may be necessary to flush or invalidate the entire cache-system, or individual lines of 32, 64 or 128 bytes can be flushed at a time)

Comment: Wondering how to put complete struct in atomic .. `struct TestWrapper { std::atomic<Struct> wrapped; `  , and ptr1 and ptr2 are *TestWrapper .

Comment: Atomic types are only available for simple types, so you have to declare each field `atomic`. Or do something else.... ;)

Comment: hmm . actually i also have a   buffer , sent to another thread to be written out to network ; I wonder if that isn't a  general design !
Thanks for help.

Comment: If you have medium sized data (in the order of kilobytes) structures, it's quite likely better to send a copy, rather than a pointer [obviously doesn't work for classes without serialization mechanisms]. Note that if you want non-coherent processors to cache-sync, the overhead is significant - the main time taken is a combination of actually writing the affected data to memory, and iterating over the affected memory area in cache-line sized chunks. So doing a copy, that potentially fits in the cache, is quite often faster than cache maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you don't need to care about implementation details like caches. The only thing you need to do is to make sure there is a C++ happens-after relation.

As Mats Petersson's answer shows, `std::atomic` is one way to achieve that. All accesses to an atomic variable are ordered, although the order might not be statically determined (i.e. if you have two threads trying to write to the same atomic variable, you can't predict which write happens last).

Another mechanism to enforce synchronization is `std::mutex`. Threads can attempt to lock a mutex, but only one thread can have a mutex locked at a time. The other threads will block. The compiler will make certain that when one thread unlocks a mutex and the next thread locks the mutex, writes by the first thread can be read by the second thread. If this requires flushing the cache, the compiler will arrange that.

Yet another mechanism is `std::atomic_thread_fence`. This is useful if you have multiple objects shared between threads (all in the same direction). Instead of making them all atomic, you can make one of them atomic and "attach" a fence to that atomic variable. You then write to the atomic variable last, and read from it first. Obviously this is best encapsulated in a class.